# RedirectToAction does not change url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC4 application. When user enters some url http://someurl.org?pageName=1000 my action method `Data(int pageName)` gets hit. I am trying to redirect to pageName=500 and using `RedirectToAction("Data", new {@pageName = 500})`.

The action method is called again but my browser url is not changing.
I even tried `RedirectResult` with the url parameter but that also doesn't work. Also it is not Ajax call so can't use Jquery for this.Any suggestions?

Comment: see your routeconfig file inside App_start folder, maybe there some is routing which your application currently loading..

Comment: Are you actually `return`ing this RedirectToAction method call from your `Data` controller action or are you just calling the `RedirectToAction` method without doing anything with the result returned from it? Could you show the code of the `Data` action?

Comment: @Bharat : nothing like that in routeconfig

Comment: @Darin : I am doing some comparison and based on that I am calling RedirectToAction if the condition satisfies

Comment: OK, please see my answer to better understand what I meant. It's not enough to call the `RedirectToAction` method. You should call the `RedirectToAction` method **AND** return the result from it from your action.

Comment: If you included more code, i.e roughly your entire action method it would be more obvious if what @DarinDimitrov says is the issue. My guess is he's right

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure that you are actually returning the result from the `RedirectToAction` call:

```
public ActionResult Data(int pageName)
{
    if (pageName == 1000)
    {
        // Notice the return statement in front of the RedirectToAction call
        return this.RedirectToAction("Data", new { pageName = 500 });
    }

    ... something else
}
```

Comment: I have used this one only.. Although it is getting data for 500 next time;browser url is not changing..When I searched google it shows jquery mobile has same problem of redirection in MVC.. but I am having desktop application